# Include images from pages in wp search.php results in default wp search

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, php, pages, search

Is there a way to include **page images** in wp search? Like I want to search through my sites **images on pages not in posts** by caption/alt text and display them in the results page as thumbnails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include the `attachment` (media) post type in search results, use the following code snippet

```
function attachment_search( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) {
       $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'attachment' ) );
       $query->set( 'post_status', array( 'publish', 'inherit' ) );
    }

   return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'attachment_search' );
```

[Source](https://casabona.org/2014/12/add-attachments-wordpress-search-results/)

However, this does not take care of how the search results are displayed but that's a discussion for another thread.

This should've worked, but if you want to add pages as well, then replace

```
$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'attachment' ) );
```

with

```
$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'attachment' ) );
```

Comment: would I just insert this into search.php?

Comment: No. Put it in functions.php or a custom plugin.

Comment: This doesn't work on my site. Maybe it's because my images are on pages not in posts? Is there a way to set the search to pages instead of posts?

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: Where's that thread, please? :)

Comment: @footstepsdesign What I meant is if you need help with additional questions, you can post that and it'll be answered separately for the sake of context.