# How do I display images with matching text in the search results page?

Tags: pages, search, gallery

My site is a bunch of images in wp default galleries with separate links on **separate pages not posts**. I want my users to be able to enter a search term and have the results page display the images that contain the search term within their caption/alt text in another wp default gallery instead of just the page that contains it. I hope this makes sense. Here's my code from search.php that displays results.

```
<div id="main"><div class="wrap cf">

<div id="main"><div class="wrap cf">

<div id="content" role="main">

<?php get_template_part('loop-header'); ?>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : global $loop_view; ?>

        <?php get_template_part('loop-actions'); ?>

        <div class="loop-content switchable-view <?php echo $loop_view; ?>" data-view="<?php echo $loop_view; ?>">
            <div class="nag cf">
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    get_template_part('item-video');
                endwhile; ?>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end .loop-content -->
```

Comment: Maybe you take a look at the [answer you already got](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/271659/15605) from the earlier question you asked!! Come with code and tell ppl where the problem is, WPSE is not a forum where ppl need to chew for you. Show some own input and maybe you get help for free.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!! I'm new to the site so I didn't know how it worked